# Custom predicate returning random results sometimes

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, thread-safety, predicate

My requirement is to find out all the matching objects with given criteria.
So what I did was created a Custom predicate and passed the matching criteria and the source IDs that should be matched with the Objects. If the condition is matching, then I am internally populating a map to hold the details.

And when the stream is completed, this map will have all the matching criteria details.
So I use this map for later computation.
Most of the time it works, but starts failing randomly.

My Custom predicate is -

```
public class IdentifierMapPredicate<T extends Identifiable, V> implements Predicate<T> {
    private static Logger           logger               = Logger
            .getLogger();
    private Collection<V>                  sourceIds;
    private BiPredicate<T, V>              matchingCondition;
    private Map<V, Collection<Identifier>> identifierMap;

    public Map<V, Collection<Identifier>> getIdentifierMap() {
        return identifierMap;
    }

    public IdentifierMapPredicate(Collection<V> sourceIds,
            BiPredicate<T, V> matchingCondition) {
        this.sourceIds = sourceIds;
        this.matchingCondition = matchingCondition;
        identifierMap = new HashMap<>(sourceIds.size());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(T t) {
        for (V id : sourceIds) {
            if (matchingCondition.test(t, id)) {
                //logger.debug("t :{}, id :{}", t.getIdentifier(), id);
                Collection<Identifier> ids = identifierMap.get(id);
                if(ids == null){
                    ids = new HashSet<>();
                    identifierMap.put(id, ids);
                }
                ids.add(t.getIdentifier());
                logger.debug("identifierMap :{}", identifierMap);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I added log statements when the criteria is matched and we update the map, sometime the map has only 1 element (even though I am expecting 2) or sometimes its 0.

2019-11-24 09:31:52.574 PST DEBUG ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 IdentifierMapPredicate:52 -  identifierMap :{}

2019-11-24 09:31:52.574 PST DEBUG ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7 IdentifierMapPredicate:52 -identifierMap :{}

Is there anything wrong with the above implementation?
Should changing it to ConcurrentHashMap will help?

Answer (score 2):

> Most of the time it works, but starts failing randomly

Yeah, classical [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

You're using `IdentifierMapPredicate` in a multi-threaded context. If you access IdentifierMapPredicate.test concurrently, threads will use also `identifierMap` simulaneously, which is not thread safe.

It looks like a ConcurrentHashMap will solve the issue. Alternatively you could modify method `test` with the `synchronized` keyword, but that will give you less throughput/more locking I'd assume. But on the other hand also less headache, its a trade-off where I'd gladly accept less headache if there aren't tight performance requirements. Just my personal preference.

Btw. nowadays you can use Map.[computeIfAbsent](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashmap-computeifabsent-method-in-java-with-examples/) to create new entries instead of

```
Collection<Identifier> ids = identifierMap.get(id);
if(ids == null){
   ids = new HashSet<>();
   identifierMap.put(id, ids);
}
```

Comment: Yes but how can this map have 0 entries at some time? At least it should have 1 entry if its being populated by multiple threads. So even if I use ConcurrentHashMap will it ensure that the no of records will be as per the expectations?

Comment: Can't comment on that. I saw an SO post once discussing the paradoxic effects of non-thread-save access, can't find it any more. But I do assume, if the stuff is done in a thread-safe way chances are good, that it behaves as expected :)

Comment: Some sort of synchronized set might be needed also instead of simple `HashSet`. Making `test` synchronized actually will transform parallel execution into singlethreaded.

Comment: I tried to run after changing it to ConcurrentHashMap, now the issue is not coming. But since the issue was intermittent, will keep trying running the flows multiple times.

Comment: I seems ok, and @Ivan's suggestion also to use a thread save alternative for HashSet seems unnecessary at a second glance. But again I'd take the no-headache route, personally.